# thunderbird script to disable option: "delete message on server"

Tags: command-line, thunderbird

When I first started using Thunderbird. I overlooked that Thunderbird
deletes message(on server) after 14 days. It gave me a **HELL** of a shock. 
When i checked my mail via web-browser(luckily hot-mail put them in my deleted folder. phew). When I updated 11.10 to 12.04 via clean install. I forgot this setting. Almost removed them again
I want to know if there is some command that can disable this settings for all my accounts in Thunderbird.
Cause i have a `install-all-12.04.sh` script that I want to put it in. With the rest of my codes.
and in the future help some **NOOBS** ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this within Thunderbird directly.
Go to Accounts>Synchronisation and Storage and in the last option ("To recover disk space...") make sure that "Don't delete any messages" is selected.

You can override this on a per-folder basis by amending the "Retention Settings" value (right click folder>properties).

Comment: I want to know if there is a command, that can disable that setting without using a gui.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a command, but you could create a user.js file to override the prefs.js file in the Thunderbird profile directory. I suspect the entries you want are probably these:

> user_pref("mail.server.server1.cleanupBodies", false);
>   user_pref("mail.server.server1.daysToKeepBodies", 30);
>   user_pref("mail.server.server1.daysToKeepHdrs", 30);

You might have to do some research into the specifics though.